# Use of -q Flag in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, compiler-flags

What does the -q flag in Python mean/do ? Also how do I access a list of the flags through the terminal (Cygwin) ? I tried help() and then -q but that said that -q could not be found.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html) for the current Python version's command line options. To be specific [this is for -q](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-q).

Comment: In Python, the '-q' command instructs the program to not display copyright and version messages, even in interactive mode.

Comment: `python --help` works to get the info on options in the terminal.